# Does Webpack provide a global error hook when a chunk load fails?

Tags: webpack, error-handling, requirejs

After a migration from RequireJS to Webpack 4, I was looking for an equivalent to [require.onError](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors) to capture runtime chunk load errors, but I couldn't find any options to add a *global* error handler.

I know that's possible to capture errors when using async `import` calls, like this one:

```
import('module/path')
.catch(function() {
    // error handling code
});
```

But, is there a Webpack option to add a generic chunk load error catch? so I can to provide further troubleshooting options to users (like a refresh the page prompt).

My app does heavy usage of async/lazy load and adding the error management code inline in every `import` call is not an option, since I need a fallback to make sure that there will be an error handler in case a dev forgets to add error management.

Comment: What about adding global error handler to document / window? Have no idea whether it will work, but you can try :)

Answer (score 5):

Encountered same problem and explored webpack 4, but couldn't find anything similar to `require.onError` in webpack for dynamic imports. I have written a babel plugin that will attach `catch` to every dynamic import and will take error handler function definition in babel plugin options.

As dynamic imports are promises so chaining promises and attaching `catch` will attach custom error handler, without causing existing code to break.

Here is the babel plugin, https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-override

P.S. I didn't want to use window.onerror and wanted specific error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack allows you to [override the `__webpack_chunk_load__` function](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_chunk_load__-webpack-specific). You can use this to intercept errors that happen when loading a chunk. Put this somewhere early in your app's initialization:

```js
const originalLoad = __webpack_chunk_load__;
__webpack_chunk_load__ = async (id) => {
  try {
    return await originalLoad(id);
  } catch (err) {
    // ...do something...
    throw err;
  }
};
```

For TypeScript type support, add this at the **top** of the file where you use `__webpack_chunk_load__`:

```
/// <reference types="webpack/module" />
```